# Thymeleaf templates in class package

Tags: spring, templates, thymeleaf

Is there a way to store Thymeleaf templates not in `resources` or `webapp`, but in the same packages as classes instead? For example structure like this:

```
com
   example
      myapp
         foo
            Foo.class
            Template.html
         bar
            Bar.class
            Template.html
            OtherTemplate.html
```

How would I have to configure Spring and Thymeleaf in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver` in the `WebMvcConfigurer`.

In the following example, the base package where I have my templates is `net.yadaframework.views` (which whould be `com.example.myapp` in your case).
When I return a view from a Controller, the path is relative to that package, so `"/foo/Template"` in your example.
The `patterns` Set should contain the subfolders of the base package, so `"/foo/*"` and `"/bar/*"` in your example.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "net.yadaframework.views" })
public class YadaWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver yadaTemplateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("net/yadaframework/views");
        /* From the tutorial:
         When several template resolvers are applied, it is recommended to specify patterns 
         for each template resolver so that Thymeleaf can quickly discard those template resolvers 
         that are not meant to resolve the template, enhancing performance. Doing this is not a 
         requirement, but a recommendation
         */
        Set<String> patterns = new HashSet<>();
        patterns.add("/yada/*"); // Start with "yada". Patterns are NOT regexp
        patterns.add("/yadacms/*"); // Start with "yadacms". Patterns are NOT regexp
        resolver.setResolvablePatterns(patterns);
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        resolver.setCacheable(true);
        resolver.setOrder(10); 
        return resolver;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like it's what I'm looking for! Is it theoretically possible to set an empty prefix and just resolve full template path (which will be in the same package as the Controller by convention) from the class canonical name? I'm going for a highly modular project, so I would like to be able to resolve such templates that are in different packages and in different modules even. Or will `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver` only work in the same module where it's declared?

Comment: I think the prefix is optional. Don't know about modules.

Comment: BTW I think it would be more elegant to stick to resources folders instead of mixing java and html files: they all end up together after compilation anyway. I have a library project with java classes under src/main/java and html files under src/main/resources and, if I use the same package structure in the resources folder, java classes and html files are jarred together. Have a look: https://github.com/xtianus/yadaframework/tree/master/YadaWeb/src/main

Comment: Thank you, that is pretty much how I do that now. I just have sort of a package naming convention for my templates that are stored in `resources`. I was trying to achieve a Tapestry-like project structure, where you can create a business object structure - a class, a template and an i18n file in one package. But that was more like a 'can I do that' kinda deal :) Thank you for the advices!